# use cuSVM without MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cuda

I want to compile cuSVM on windows x64 but without using MATLAB. I dont want to use MATLAB at all. I searched Google and it shows results with MATLAB. Can anyone suggest  away, a link or an alternate?

Answer (score 2):

Short Version: cuSVM is a *MATLAB Toolbox* for Gaussian-kernel Support Vector Machines. Thus you will need MATLAB to use it.

Long(er) Version: As cuSVM is a collection of MEX-Files and the C++ source code is provided, you can easily identify the `mexFunction`'s which are called from MATLAB. These are normally just wrapper-functions, where the input data is read, checked and converted to a standard C++ format, e.g. to `double`. Then a worker-function is called from there. I have checked the source of this cuSVM library and this appears to be the case there too. Now you could write similar wrapper-functions to interface the worker-functions any way you'd like, e.g. from C or C++ or whatever. This requires some work, but should be possible in a reasonable amount of time.